# how do I call an object arraylist method from inside an external class

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexing, methods

I want to call **theArrayList()** method from an external class that displays the contents inside of object arraylist titled **theList**. How would I be able to accomplish this?

mendietaRAL.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class mendietaRAL {
  public static void theArrayList() {
    ArrayList<Object> theList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    theList.add(123);
    theList.add("Java");
    theList.add(3.75);
    theList.add("Summer C");
    theList.add(2018);

    for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++) {
      System.out.print(theList.get(i));
    }

    theList.remove(1);
    theList.remove(4);

    for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++) {
      System.out.print(theList.get(i));
    }
  }
}
```

mendietaRpgm2.java

```
public class mendietaRpgm2 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

  }
}
```

Comment: `public static void main(String args[]) { mendietaRAL.theArrayList();  }` ?

Comment: @lealceldeiro When i try that method I get this: mendietaRpgm2.java:3: error: package com.something does not exist
import com.something.mendietaRAL;
                    ^
mendietaRpgm2.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    mendietaRAL.theArrayList();
    ^
  symbol:   variable mendietaRAL
  location: class mendietaRpgm2

Comment: You just need to import `mendietaRAL` into `mendietaRpgm2` class.

Answer (score 0):

You call a static method by the class name `mendietaRAL` (this should start with uppercase) and the method `theArrayList`.... so you would do (see below)... but make sure to capitalize that class name because this makes mendietaRAL appear to be a variable

```
import com.something.mendietaRAL;

public class mendietaRpgm2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         mendietaRAL.theArrayList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class mendietaRpgm2 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
   mendietaRAL.theArrayList();
  }
}
```

Please change your class name to MendietaRpgm2. Look at the naming conventions [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). 
Also, remove the unused ArrayList import.